# How to persist null value from server? (Groovy and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, groovy, model, null

I'm returning an object (`cmd`) in the model from my Groovy controller. However, in the JavaScript in the GSP, it's converting null values to empty strings.

For instance,

```
<script>
  name:'${cmd.name.encodeAsHTML()}'
</script>
```

Omitting the quotes around the interpolation piece throws an error. How can I force the null value from the server side to be preserved?

Comment: unlike JSON, HTML has no `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
name: ${cmd.name ? "'" + cmd.name.encodeAsHTML() + "'" : "null"}
```

or some variation of that, which should render:

```
name: 'some name'
```

-or-

```
name: null
```

I think this is what you are looking for.